# CodeIgniter controller and cPanel subfolder has same name

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, cpanel

After removing "**index.php**" from URL using instructions described [*here*](http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-htaccess-remove-index-php/),
cPanel sub-folder is requested when I call a codeIgniter controller which has same name as sub-folder.

Controller and sub-folder name is "sites". So, when I request

> example.com/sites

Instead of requesting controller **example.com/index.php/sites**, it requests sub-folder "**sites**".

It can be fixed by deleting sub-folder or renaming the controller, BUT I want to know if there is any other solution to resolve this issue.

Thank You!

Comment: something like this: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that via htaccess Rules.

Try this rule:-

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
// Below line will controller instead of directory
RewriteRule ^sites/?$ index.php/sites [L]
```

OR

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: If it is useful then accept the answer so future visitor can find it as useful :)

Comment: Is it a good practice to remove `#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` to make it generic? To ignore sub-directories and send request **index.php** every time.

Comment: It's not ignoring sub directories.  check this link for more detail:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/34875835/4198099

Comment: In that answer you said **"-d (is test string a valid directory)"**. Doesn't that mean, if we remove this than it will ignore sub-directories? Thank you!

Comment: Okay. Now I am getting your question. Yes you are correct. If we remove it then it will ignore sub-directories.