# Redirect all Http requests to Https in Laravel 5

Tags: php, http, laravel, https, laravel-5

I am trying to redirect all my http requests to https in Laravel 5. Is there any documentation in Laravel 5 for this action. Else, Help me with code how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to redirect back or redirect any particular page or what ?????

Comment: You need to make changes in your `.htaccess` file if you're using a APACHE serve. Read more here http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/05/27/redirecting-to-https-in-laravel-5/

Comment: Use middleware: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https

Comment: I need to redirect all pages to https if he request http

Comment: Check my update answer

Answer (score 2):

You can do redirection from http to https with htaccess file. Put below code in your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

OR

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
// change example.com with your website domain
// This will redirect all requests received on port 80 to HTTPS.
```

To understand how rules are working check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875653/remove-php-extension-of-website-with-htaccess/34875835#34875835).

In many cases, you can also just add those lines to a file named .htaccess in the folder that you want to redirect http to https.

Now, when a visitor types http://www.yoursite.com/mypage.htm the server will automatically redirect http to https so that they go to https://www.yoursite.com/mypage.htm

**Note**: You can also redirect a single page from http to http in Apache by using this in your configuration file or .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^apache-redirect-http-to-https\.html$ https://www.yoursite.com/apache-redirect-http-to-https.html [R=301,L]
```

This [link](http://www.codexworld.com/redirect-non-www-to-www-http-to-https-using-htaccess-file/) will also help you.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I need to redirect pages from http to https. Say, I have http://example.com/user, I need to redirect that to https://example.com/user. I tried with the above code in laravel 5, its redirecting to index.php

Answer (score 1):

hey to redirect any pages you have to use in your controller on top

```
use Redirect;
```

in your function you can call which you want like this

```
return Redirect::route('foldername.filename') //ex - return Redirect::route('consignees.show')
```

and redirect back you can use this

```
return redirect()->back();
```

check this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses)