# Why do I need to add index.php in order to route my website correctly? [getkirby]

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing, web-hosting, kirby

I uploaded the code to the server. It started the homepage correctly . But when I press any link , I get 404 not found error. I discovered that I need to add index.php to my url for it to work.
so it will be like that:

> mydomain.somee.com/myWebsite/index.php/anotherPage

When I was working locally using Xamp as a server, I didn't get any of those problems.
I got those problems after I uploaded the website to some.com which apparently doesn't use .htaccess file (editing or removing has no effect).

How to add this index.php automatically and hide it from the user?

I didn't change any of the system files or the htaccess
please tell me if you need anymore files or description.

Comment: What's inside your .htaccess ?

Comment: index.php is generally DirectoryIndex file. You can set it to whatever e.g. home.php or default.php. This is entry script for the project/folder.

Comment: the .htaccess should work fine for any php apace server . but the server i used is windows virtual server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect all your all pages through index.php file but remove it from URL.

Write below rules in your root .`htaccess` file:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

OR

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

To understand, How htaccess rules are working, This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875653/remove-php-extension-of-website-with-htaccess/34875835#34875835) will help you :)

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: thanks for the first replay, 
the first part is already written in the .access by default.
the problem is that : Somee.com uses windows virtual server which doesn't use .htaccess apparently